# How to get confidence interval from RNN?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, statistics, time-series

I am working on time series prediction using RNN and tensorflow. I am not sure how to get confidence interval from the distribution which may or may not be defined in the internal memory state of the `rnn_decoder`.

This way I can plot the distribution like ARIMA:

[image: arima]

or Gaussian Process

[image: GP]

Here is the code I am working on:

https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/seq2seq-signal-prediction

Here is the definition for `tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.basic_rnn_seq2seq`.

```
  with variable_scope.variable_scope(scope or "basic_rnn_seq2seq"):
    enc_cell = copy.deepcopy(cell)
    _, enc_state = rnn.static_rnn(enc_cell, encoder_inputs, dtype=dtype)
    return rnn_decoder(decoder_inputs, enc_state, cell)
```

And [rnn_decoder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py#L112)

It should be similar to logits in the discrete case(namely softmax cross entropy). I have tried passing a custom loop function in the decoder but the code was not working at all. My second guess was to write a custom decoder but need someone pointing to the right direction.

Comment: I have been looking into Mixture Density Networks. Still not sure how to use it though.